# Modify Sonar jdk in Jenkins job from groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins, sonarqube

How does one set the jdk version from a groovy script for Sonar to use within Jenkins job configuration. I require the sonar jdk to be different from the jobs actual jdk which is used to build via maven. I have managed to get to stage where I can retrieve the jobs jdk version used by Sonar but can't find a way to set it. Any suggestions?

```
import hudson.util.*;
import hudson.tasks.Publisher;

def h = Hudson.getInstance();
def projects = h.getProjects();

for (project in projects) {
    def DescribableList<Publisher,Descriptor<Publisher>> publishers = project.getPublishersList();
    for (publisher in publishers) {
      def desc = publisher.getDescriptor();
      if (desc.getId().equals("hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher")) {
        println(publisher.getJDK());        
        //((hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher) publisher).setJDK(h.getJDK("Sun JDK 1.7.45"));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can define a different JDK at all? I mean through the UI? When I look at the source of SonarPublisher it seems that getJdk() just delegates to the Jenkins/Hudson instance. That would mean you can't override the JDK used for Sonar.

Comment: When one accesses the confgiure page and navigate to sonar and then press advanced button a drop down is visible to set JDK used.

Answer (score 0):

As SonarPublisher do not have setters for jdk, you need to replace the actual instance by a new one in job's publishers:

```
def jobs = Hudson.instance.getItems(AbstractProject.class)

jobs.each {
  sonar = it.publishersList.get(hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.class)
  if(sonar){
     newSonar = new hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher(
        sonar.installationName,
        sonar.branch,
        sonar.language,
        sonar.triggers,
        sonar.jobAdditionalProperties,
        sonar.mavenOpts,
        sonar.mavenInstallationName,
        sonar.rootPom,
        "Oracle 1.8.0", //set your JDK name here
        sonar.settings,
        sonar.globalSettings,
        sonar.usePrivateRepository)

    it.publishersList.replace(newSonar)
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher(null, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, null, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, null, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider, jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider, java.lang.Boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of the SonarPublisher (I'm using SonarQube Scanner 2.8), you can set the JDK directly, so this works for me:

```
def jobs = Hudson.instance.getItems(AbstractProject.class)

jobs.each {
    sonar = it.publishersList.get(hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.class)
    if(sonar) {
        sonar.setJdk("jdk18") // set your JDK name here
        it.publishersList.replace(sonar)
    }
}
```